# How to configure eclipse to keep this code format?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, playframework-2.0

Following code is from a sample of playframework-2.0:

```
/**
 * Display the dashboard.
 */
public static Result index() {
    return ok(
        dashboard.render(
            Project.findInvolving(request().username()),
            Task.findTodoInvolving(request().username()),
            User.find.byId(request().username())
        )
    );
}
```

It looks good, but when I use code format of eclipse, it becomes:

```
/**
 * Display the dashboard.
 */
public static Result index() {
    return ok(dashboard.render(
        Project.findInvolving(request().username()),
        Task.findTodoInvolving(request().username()),
        User.find.byId(request().username())
        ));
}
```

How to configure eclipse to keep to first format style? I tried a lot, but not works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to using `Code Formatter` in eclipse. You can find it in following path:

1. `windows` menu and in `Preferences` item.
2. go to `java` in left tree.
3. go to `code style` sub-tree of `java`.
4. select `Formatter` leaf.
5. click `Edit` button and edit your customize formate and save it.

I recomend you save your customization environment such as formatter and use it in others place. `Eclipse` hold `formatter` information in a xml file. you can specify path of this file.

following link is useful:

- http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/

Comment: Thanks, but what I wonder is how to configure eclipse to get the same format of first one. I tried to configure eclipse a lot, but the final style is not as expected

Comment: You have to test several option in `eclipse formatter`. I guess you want wrap method call (`return ok(dashboard.render()...`), for this goal go to `Line Wrapping` tab in `Formatter` and select `Function Call` of following tree and select `Wrap all elements, every element on a new line` item in `Line wrapping policy` combo box and will see preview of result in right area. I recomend you see all feature of `Formatter`.