# how to format code in eclipse "git repository browsing prespective"?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin

How to format code to specific coding style in `Git Repository perspective` in Eclipse ? like `Ctrl+shift+f` works in Java perspective. Can anybody help me to solve this ?

Here My problem is to format a android repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure eclipse to keep this code format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989142/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-keep-this-code-format) I don't see what this has to do with android or git.

Comment: Please read the whole question. I want formatting in git repository prespective formatting

Comment: I did read the whole question, and it was not clear. Please clarify. You want to be able to use the `Ctrl+shift+f` keyboard shortcut in that perspective? Or you just want the code to _be_ formatted differently in that perspective?

Comment: i want Ctrl+shift+f in that prespective or even any other way of formatting in that prespective

Comment: I don't know why there are two close votes and a downvote :D But i am waiting anybodey to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it was very easy,

```
Right Click on project in Git perspective -> import project -> check import as a general project ->select the working directory which you want to import -> finish
```

Now go to the java perspective and find the project  :) thats all

Answer (score 1):

The "format" actions are tied to specific editors. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice in a row to open the list of all available hotkeys. Filter that list on "format" and you should see a number of potential candidates... and their context. The Java <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Format) action is available in any Java editor ... even when in the Git perspective (at least, that's true with Eclipse 4.2 as I just tried it). That is, as long as you have a Java editor open and it has focus. The Ant "format" action should work the same way : as long as you have an "ant build file" editor opened and focused.

Whether the "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>" *you* want is active or not depends on *which* action exactly you are trying to trigger : java format, ant format, xtext format... and how *that* specific action is contributed (and bound) by its contributing plugin. To check that, you can open an editor where you know the action is active, hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then right-click your editor and locate the "format" action. When you click that action just after <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> has been pressed, it will not be triggered : rather, a dialog will pop-up to tell you which action that is, who contributes it, through which plugin.xml...

Comment: I am using Version: 3.7.2 and ctrl+shift+f wont work at all in git browsing prespective but it works in java perspective, and what i can do to enable java formater in git prespective ?

Comment: Formatting a Java file does work in Eclipse 3.7.2 even when on the Git perspective. make sure that the file you opened is actually in your workspace, and not something you opened within the repository without importing it. A file that is on the repository but not imported in your workspace is simply read-only. Formatting won't work if you are "editing" a read-only file or if you are not using the Java editor.